# How to append columns in the grid dynamically for devexpress datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I am using devexpress winforms grid.

I bind data from a dataset to the devexpress grid.

```
 dataGrid.MainView.GridControl.DataSource = ds;
 dataGrid.MainView = gridView;
 gridView.BestFitColumns();
```

Grid display would be like this

```
 FirstName  LastName    
 Sharp      Eye
```

I call RowStyle event to display background color for rows in the grid based on condition.

For ex:

```
private void gridViewExcel_RowStyle(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowStyleEventArgs e)
{
    GridView View = sender as GridView;
    string firstName = View.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, View.Columns["FirstName"]);

      if (firstName="Sharp")
      {
        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
        e.Appearance.BackColor2 = Color.White;
      } 
     else
     {
        //I want to append another column in the end to the dataset that is bound to the grid.
        //With an error message...(see below)
     }
}
```

Output

```
 FirstName LastName     Message

 Sharp        Eye      First name doesn't match
```

Comment: Why not add one more column to your datatable? or add `UnBoundGridColumn` to grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't conditionally show an extra column on specific rows. 
One approach for your problem would be to add a "Message" column to the DataSource before you bind it to the Grid. And then change the text in this column if a row has an error.

Comment: Another option would be to show a cell or row error icon with a tool tip.

Comment: see link for more information http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1933

Answer (score 2):

You can instantiate a DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn() at runtime.

Ex :

```
DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn colMessage= newDevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn();

colMessage.Caption = "Message";
colMessage.FieldName = "<bound datafield>";
colMessage.Name = "colMessage";
colMessage.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = false;
colMessage.OptionsColumn.FixedWidth = true;
colMessage.OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = true;
colMessage.Visible = true;
colMessage.VisibleIndex = 0;
colMessage.Width = 80;
View.Columns.AddRange(newDevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn[] {
            this.colMessage});
```

It's also possible to declare an unbound column and filling it with gridView events

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with devexpress specifically, but I think you would be better off analyzing your data before binding it to the grid.  When is gridViewExcel_RowStyle called?  You want to avoid heavy logic if it's called frequently.

If you really want the logic here you should be able to get the dataset from the bound source (or from a field) and add the column as needed.

```
GridView View = sender as GridView;
    string firstName = View.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, View.Columns["FirstName"]);

      if (firstName=="Sharp")
      {
        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
        e.Appearance.BackColor2 = Color.White;
      } 
     else
 {   

     DataSet ds = view.DataSource as DataSet;
     if(ds != null)
     {
         //add the column to the table you want if it doesn't exist
     }
 }
```